# Dojo Grid excel

Tags: dojo, grid

I have read you was previosly trying to make some changes to dojo widget to achive better behaviour. Im asking because I have a similar task, and I dont want to reinvent the wheel, and would be very helpful if some1 can share experience. 
Thanx Fornwald Ladislav

Answer (score 1):

You can extend existing widgets and override their functions to provide your own custom implementations without having to rewrite entire controls.

This can get you started: [Dojo - Writing Your Own Widget](http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/writingWidgets?highlight=%28custom%29|%28widget%29)